# Hiding the tool bar entries from plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can we hide the tool bar entries in eclipse from plugin as shown in the image.
[image]

In the tool bar how can we hide only the perspective as shown in figure.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me in hiding perspective toolbar entries.

```
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            if (window instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
                MTrimBar topTrim = ((WorkbenchWindow) window).getTopTrim();
            for (MTrimElement element : topTrim.getChildren()) {
                if ("PerspectiveSwitcher".equals(element.getElementId())) {                     
                    element.setVisible(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

That menu item (which toggles the  toolbar on/off) uses a command with the id `org.eclipse.ui.ToggleCoolbarAction`. So you need to execute that command.

You can execute a command using the `IHandlerService`:

```java
IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.ui.ToggleCoolbarAction", null);
```

Comment: Right this will hide the tool bar. But can we hide only the tool bar entries using this command for EX: Only Perspective entry

Comment: No you can't. I don't believe there is a straightforward way to do that. You might be able to use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension for that or maybe CSS but it will require a lot of research.